# Matplotlib 'eps' export using savefig generates error when using TeX in figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, eps

I am trying to export a figure which is rendered using TeX. I use the following minimal example code to accomplish this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.savefig('plot.eps', format='eps')
```

This generates an error:

> RuntimeError: ghostscript was not able to process your image.
>   Here is the full report generated by ghostscript:

(it doesn't actually provide the full report)

Now if i render without TeX then everything works fine:

```
rc('text', usetex=False)
```

Also rendering with TeX and outputting to PNG or PDF works fine aswell.

Anyone know what is going on?